# How to increase local variable value in return function

Tags: javascript, local-variables

I had declared a variable in constructor like

```
this.sno=1;
```

and i use this in my return function like

```
this.sno++
```

but it's not giving me proper values

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you use the `++` operator in postfix mode, your variable is incremented, but you get back the value of the variable before it was incremented.

Use `++this.sno` (`++` in prefix mode) to get the incremented value.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed there is reactjs tag so I recommend using the component state to save this data and then you can do like the above answer said or simply do

```js
return this.state.sno +1;
```

Answer (score 0):

the value get incremented with post-fix notation. below is simple example:

```
this.sno=1
output = 1

++this.sno;
output = 2

this.sno++
   output = 2

//here the value get incrmented but output show 2 but the value of sno = 3 

++this.sno
   output = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid confusion between post- and prefix notations, you can use `+=`:

```
this.sno+=1
```